# Do bonuses from the Hallowed Ground Numen add dice or successes?

Tags: demon-the-descent

The Hallowed Ground numen states:

> The angel decrees what will be and fate works to help humans comply. Anyone who hears the angel’s decree and acts towards fulfilling its goal adds the angel’s Rank to his rolls.

For an angel of rank 3, do you add three dice or three successes to the human's rolls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You add dice to the roll

As you already listed: **emphasis mine**

> The angel decrees what will be and fate works to help humans comply. Anyone who hears the angel’s decree and acts towards fulfilling its goal adds the angel’s Rank **to his rolls.**

Add to his rolls in this case means you add the rank to your dice pool. If you would have received extra successes it would have explicitly said this